# Having issues updating a document thats retrieved using a Mongoose model and processed as a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, mongodb-query, mongoose-schema

**Jump to update #2 for some closer detail**

Im having issues with a simple update to a document retrieved from querying a container via a Mongoose model. The `find` query does have two populations, but other than that, im not sure what the issue could be

The problem I'm running into, is when I retrieve a document, update a property, then attempt to save the updates to the document via Mongooses `Doc.save()` method, nothing seems to happen. Whats weird, is it the save() doesn't even fire off the callback passed to it.. (Or fire off the `then()` or `catch()` if I handle it as a Promise)

#### Model: Asset

```js
module.exports = Mongoose => {
    const Schema = Mongoose.Schema

    const assetSchema = new Schema({
        attributes: [{
            _field: {
                type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref: 'Field',
                required: true
            },
            value: {
                type: Schema.Types.Mixed,
                required: true
            }
        }],
        _partition: {
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Partition'
        }
    })

    return Mongoose.model( 'Asset', assetSchema )
}
```

And just for some detail, heres an example result from the same `find` query with the same two populations

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("56b626dc4040b5383696d16f"),
        "_partition" : { 
            _fields: [Object],
            name: 'Server stuff',
            _id: ObjectId("56ae4707f3d4645b2e5b0537")
        },
        "attributes" : [
            {
                _field: {
                    _id: ObjectId("56ae4703f3d4645b2e5b0534"),
                    name: 'Hostname'
                },
                value: 'server-04.foobar.ad',
                _id: ObjectId("56b626dc4040b5383696d172")
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

#### Document Query

Heres the code example of where I retrieve some documents via the `Foo.find` method (which works), and update the value of the first attribute (which I works), but when I try to `a.save()` the doc.. nothing happens:

```js
Asset
    .find( { _id: '56b6568cb5195902381f6c65' } )
    .populate( { path: 'attributes._field' } )
    .populate( { path: '_partition' } )
    .then( docs => {
        if( ! docs )
            throw new Error(`No docs were found`)

        console.log('# Docs Found:', docs.length) // 1
        console.log('# Instance?:', docs[0] instanceof Asset) // true
        console.log('# Docs:', assets) // Shows single document inside array

        let a = docs[0]

        a.attributes[0].value = 'blah'

        // This is where the problem is, nothing below here is displayed in the console
        a.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                throw new Error('Failed to update:' + err)

            console.log('Updated!')
        })

    } )
    .catch( err => console.error( 'ERROR:',err ) )
    .finally( () => Mongoose.connection.close() )
```

In the console, everything displays as expected, right up until the `a.save()`..  Neither an error or `Updated!` is displayed.

It's definitely a Mongoose document that I'm interacting with (the `a instanceof Foo` shows true), so I'm not at all sure why the save() isn't doing anything..

I tried to handle `a.save()` as a Promise, instead of handing a callback to it, and again, nothing happened at all, neither the `then` or `catch` was executed.

This is driving me crazy!! Im sure its something stupid that I've overlooked, but I cant seem to find it. Any help would be appreceated

**P.S.** I didn't include the *Partition* or *Field* models/schemas because I highly doubt they are related... But if someone thinks so, just let me know

**P.S.S.** Just an FYI, the MongoDB user *does* have write access

#### Update #1

Per a suggestion from @JohnnyHK, I tried to execute `Doc.markModified()`:

```js
Asset
    .find( { _id: '56b6568cb5195902381f6c65' } )
    .populate( { path: 'attributes._field' } )
    .populate( { path: '_partition' } )
    .then( docs => {
        if( ! docs )
            throw new Error(`No docs were found`)

        console.log('# Docs Found:', docs.length) // 1
        console.log('# Instance?:', docs[0] instanceof Asset) // true
        console.log('# Docs:', assets) // Shows single document inside array

        let a = docs[0]

        a.attributes[0].value = 'blah'

        a.markModified('attributes')

        // This is where the problem is, nothing below here is displayed in the console
        a.save(function (err) {
            if (err)
                throw new Error('Failed to update:' + err)

            console.log('Updated!')
        })

    } )
    .catch( err => console.error( 'ERROR:',err ) )
    .finally( () => Mongoose.connection.close() )
```

No changes... Nothing in the `a.save()` is displayed in the console, and the doc isn't updated

#### Update #2

After some tinkering.. it seems to be related to it being a promise..

This is **Successful**:

```js
// AS A CALLBACK
Asset.find( { _id: '56b6568cb5195902381f6c65' } )
    .populate( { path: 'attributes._field' } )
    .populate( { path: '_partition' } )
    .exec(function (err, doc) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err)

    doc[0].attributes[0].value = 'FOO'

    doc[0].save(function (err) {
        if (err) throw new Error(err)

        console.log('Updated to:',doc[0])

        Mongoose.connection.close()
    })
})
```

This is **UNSUCCESSFUL**:

```js
// AS A PROMISE

import Promise from 'bluebird'
Mongoose.Promise = Promise
// ..
Asset.find( { _id: '56b6568cb5195902381f6c65' } )
    .populate( { path: 'attributes._field' } )
    .populate( { path: '_partition' } )
    .then( doc => {
        doc[0].attributes[0].value = 'FOO'

        doc[0].save(function (err) {
            if (err) throw new Error(err)

            console.log('Updated to:',doc[0])
        })
    })
    .catch( err => {
        throw new Error(err)
    })
    .finally( () => Mongoose.connection.close() )
```

The only difference I can think of is the promise, as opposed to a callback

Whats *super weird*... is some of the code inside the `.then()` executes..  Just not the `save()`

#### UPDATE #3

I created a [github issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3865), and per my last update..

I found [this issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1431#issuecomment-90287156), where his "solution" was to downgrade an entire major version, from 4.X to 3.X...

The version im currently at is **^4.3.7**, I tried to change it to **3.8.35**, which the downgrade went fine but then the script itself threw a bunch of errors... Which honestly, id rather really not use such an old version anyways.

Comment: Is there any problem without the forEach loop?

Comment: No, because it outputs the `# Foo instance? true`

Comment: OK, but without the forEach is there any 'Updated!' in the console?

Comment: Nope, there isnt. I updated the original, removed the `_.forEach`

Comment: @johnnyHK Not sure about that, in his code, the console output from the `user.save` is displayed, mine isnt.. its like in my case, `save()` isnt even being executed

Comment: @JohnnyHk Updated the original post, added the `a.markModified()`, with no succes

Comment: As you can see in the last update, I just found its related to it being in a promise.. So weird

Comment: have you tried doing the `user.save` operation inside of `process.nextTick`?

Comment: @jamesChoi - I have no idea what the `process.nextTick` is, how is that supposed to fix it? (Googling it). I opened a [Github Issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/3865), and I found that someone else is having a similar issue (thought they had a very unconventional fix). For now, I bandaided the problem by using [callbacks](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html), but thats not a fix by any means

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I replicated the issue you are having using the schema you have provided and found a solution.  The following worked for me and updated the `.value` property.  Try prepending `return` to `doc[0].save()` to return it as mentioned in [this article](http://eddywashere.com/blog/switching-out-callbacks-with-promises-in-mongoose/)

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
// .....


Asset.find( { _id: '56b6568cb5195902381f6c65' } )
    .populate( { path: 'attributes._field' } )
    .populate( { path: '_partition' } )
    .exec()       // Queries aren't full-fledged promises!
    .then( doc => {
        console.log('Before:',doc[0]);
        doc[0].attributes[0].value = 'FOO'

        // Return a promise!
        return doc[0].save(function(err){
            console.log('Updated to:', doc[0]);
        });
    })
    .catch( err => {
        throw new Error(err)
    })
    .finally( () => Mongoose.connection.close() )
```

I also use `.exec()` because according to the docs [queries aren't full-fledged promises](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html#queries-are-not-promises) (just in case).  Since `.save()` returns a promise, you should return it so that the promises resolve sequentially; waiting until previous promises complete before executing.  Posted the code [here](https://gist.github.com/kizzlebot/aa17211697fd48cf11c2)

Comment: Not sure what the difference is, but one of the Mongo devs was able to verify it was an issue, and I found one other person with the exact same problem. They added it to the [Mongoose 4.4.3 milestones](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/milestones/4.4.3). For now, I just started using Bluebirds [asCallback](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html), which gets me around it for now

Comment: I mean, I was able to replicate your issue and do see that the callback to `.save()` isn't being fired.  But adding `return` to it fixed it.  The value returned by `.save()` is a promise so returning it will cause sequential execution

Comment: @Justin it's the little thing that get ya sometimes. Hope it helped

Comment: Definitely did... I kept thinking "That cant be it, theres plenty of models being updated/saved without me returning the document query", then I went back and looked through the code, and noticed they were all `new` instances, meaning just `new Something().save()`, which apparently doesnt need to be returned.. I wonder why it does in this case

Comment: @Justin when the callback to `then()` returns a value, I only seen it return a value which gets passed to the next `then()` callback as argument which also does something similar until the promise chain completes, in this case `finally()`.   Then I saw the article I mentioned in post and seen how it returns a promise instead of a value.   A bit of experimenting and I noticed it